# JSON call giving value that is not actually in the .json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a little new when it comes to JSON and Javascript , so please excuse me if if this is a stupid question, but I have run into a problem that is starting to drive me insane.

On a webpage I am including two scripts; jQuery and a file called "scripts2.js". In the same directory as scripts2.js, I have a JSON file; "settings.json". From within my "scripts2.js" file I am running he following code inside of a function.

```js
var settingsPath = settings.json;

jQuery.getJSON(settingsPath, function (data){
  jQuery.each(data, function(index){
    console.log("!"+data[index].name);
    /*unrelated other stuff */   


  });
});
```

Previously the settings.json file looked like this

```js
[
 {"name":"Standard Black"},
 {"name":"Gold"},
 {"name":"Silver"}
]
```

So naturally when I looked in the Chrome Dev Console the log would print out

!Standard Black

!Gold

!Silver

However, when testing what would happen upon editing my settings.json file I changed "name":"Gold" to "name":"Test".

```js
[
     {"name":"Standard Black"},
     {"name":"Test"},
     {"name":"Silver"}
]
```

After the json updates I tried refreshing the page but my console log is still printing out

!Standard Black

!Gold

!Silver

...

I am at a loss. I have no idea why the data being retrieved with jQuery.getJSON() is sending the data of my old settings.json even after the changes has been saved. I have perused my .php file (which is generating the HTML) , as well as my included javascript and there is no other mention of another json file or any sort of clone of my json file in any related directory.
I really have no idea what is going on and I am starting to go insane. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue might be?

I dont know if it matters but I am running a XAMPP stack on my localhost. All files (index.php, scripts2.js, and settings.json) are in a directory located inside XAMPP's htdocs folder.

EDIT: Thank you all for the speedy and thorough answers, many of you answered the question I was a bout to ask next. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser is caching the file from your first request.  Simply clear the cache and run it again and the new data will be retrieved.

**UPDATE:**

To prevent the browser from caching this file, change your AJAX settings like so:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Before you make the getJSON call

Comment: It will ask browser to make every request as new request even the url is not changing.It will not take the advantage of browser cache feature

Comment: That's what the OP asked for in a comment that was deleted.

Comment: It was asked in a comment that was deleted.  Then the question was updated saying that we answered what he was about to ask next.  Trust me, it was asked, you just missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing web cache and restart local servers if you have not already

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     success: success
```

});

So, set the optional parameter cache  to false (this value by default is always true):

```
$.ajax({
     dataType: "json",
     url: url,
     data: data,
     cache: false,   // If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser
     success: success
```

});

Therefore, your getJson becomes:

```
    var settingsPath = settings.json;

    jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: settingsPath,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery.each(data, function (index) {
                console.log("!" + data[index].name);
                /*unrelated other stuff */


            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `jQuery.ajax()` instead of the shorthand method, you can disable caching like this:

```
jQuery.ajax(settingsPath, {cache: false})
```

jQuery will append a timestamp parameter to your request URL which changes with every request and therefore keeps the browser from caching the response.

Comment: It will ask browser to make every request as new request even the url is not changing.It will not take the advantage of browser cache feature

Answer (score 0):

To force the browser to get a new version each time  you can use `cache: false` in `jQuery.ajax()`

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: settingsPath,
  cache: false,
  success: function (data){
      $.each(data, function(index){
         console.log("!"+data[index].name);
      });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass additional parameter to your requested `url` which value will change with every request.So,your browser will consider it as new request every time and will not cache the data.

```
var random = Math.round(new Date().getTime())

    var settingsPath = 'settings.json&time=' + random;

    jQuery.getJSON(settingsPath, function(data) {

      });
    });
```

You can use any algoritham that generate random new value everytime for `random` for every request.

OR

you can have same things with [jQuery#Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method